# cmake: How to add a add_custom_command that just executes a shellscript?

Tags: makefile, build-process, cmake

When I use the classic gnu Make I put in post build actions like flash the device (if it is a embedded device) and other similiar actions. The actual flashing is usually hidden behind a little sctipt or some commands.

Then I can type something like

```
make flash
```

so I first build the code and then it ends up on the target.
The classic Makefile could have something like in it:

```
.PHONY: flash
flash: main.bin
    scripts/do_flash.pl main.bin
```

But how do I add this kind of post build actions to a cmake build?

How do I add a "custom command" that just executes a shellscript?

This questions talks about add_custom_command: 
The question [cmake add custom command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354473/cmake-add-custom-command) feels like it is close, 
but the add_custom_command seems to need a "output file" to work.
But in this case there is something happening, not generated.

What would I put in the CMakeLists.txt to add such a custom action?

/Thanks

---

For reference, a link into the cmake documentation on this topic

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command:add_custom_target

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_custom_target(flash
    COMMAND ${PERL_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/do_flash.pl ${MAIN_BIN_FILE}
    DEPENDS ${MAIN_BIN_FILE}
)
```

Comment: btw, how do you know that ${MAIN_BIN_FILE} should transform into main.bin? Is there some kind of cmake magic, or shall I define a varialbe called MAIN_BIN_FILE and give him the value main.bin?

Comment: Yup, you should define it yourself. I assumed that you will be producing main.bin by add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${MAIN_BIN_FILE} ...). If it's not the case you can replace it with constant string. In that case you can also remove DEPENDS clause from add_custom_target.

Comment: I have not converted my project into cmake yet, I'm trying to find out if I can convert and what I will gain/lose if I do switch.

Comment: I think this can work, tricky with the internal strings that sometimes needs to have "" and sometimes not... but with some printing with the "message" command I think I can handle that.

Comment: There is difference with writing set(var string1 string2) and set(var "string1 string2"). In first case you a creating a list (';'-delimited string) with two elements and in the second case it's just plain string. Such CMake functions as add_custom_*() are accepting lists, not strings, so be сareful with quotes.