# CMake with regarding generated files

Tags: cmake, dynamically-generated, tntnet

Good day everyone.

I have the following situation: I have a CMake file, which is supposed to compile my application, which consists of:

1. one or more `cpp` files
2. some template files (`ecpp`), which on their turn are generated into `cpp` files, which are compiled into the application (they are listed below in the `WEB_COMPONENTS` so for each component there is the associated `.ecpp` file and the `.cpp` that will be generated from it).

And here is the CMakeLists.txt (simplified)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
set (PROJECT sinfonifry)
set (ECPPC /usr/local/bin/ecppc)
set (WEB_COMPONENTS 
     images 
     menu
     css
)

set(${PROJECT}_SOURCES
  ""
  CACHE INTERNAL ${PROJECT}_SOURCES
)

foreach(comp ${WEB_COMPONENTS})
  list(APPEND ${PROJECT}_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${comp}.cpp )

  execute_process(COMMAND ${ECPPC} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${comp}.cpp -v
                  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${comp}.ecpp 
                  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} OUTPUT_QUIET
                 )
endforeach()

list(APPEND ${PROJECT}_SOURCES main.cpp )
add_executable(${PROJECT}_exe ${${PROJECT}_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT}_exe cxxtools dl tntnet tntdb)
```

Now, what happens: for the very first time (ie: make the build directory, run cmake-gui, select web component, configure, generate, make) the CMake nicely executes the `${ECPPC}` command, ie. it generates the required CPP files in the binary directory, and links them together.

After a while, obviously while I work, I modify one of the component files (such as `images.ecpp`) and run `make` again in the build directory. But now, CMake does not pick up the changes of the `ecpp` files. I have to go to cmake-gui, delete cache, restart everything from zero. This is very tiresome and slow.

So, two questions:

1. Cand I tell CMake to track the changes of the `images.ecpp` and call the `${ECPPC}` compiler on it if it changed?
2. How can I `make clean` so that it also removes the generated `cpp` files.

Thank you for your time, f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `execute_process()` you want to use `add_custom_command()`.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2362222/4323

Basically you tell CMake the `OUTPUT` (the generated filename), `COMMAND`, and `DEPENDS` (the .ecpp filename).  This makes it understand how to turn the source into the necessary C++ generated file.  Then, add the generated file to some target, e.g. `add_executable()`, or to an `add_custom_command()` dependency (if it didn't need to be compiled you'd more likely need that).

Comment: Excellent. Just to share the command:   `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${comp}.cpp
                     COMMAND ${ECPPC} -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${comp}.cpp -v -n ${comp} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${comp}.ecpp
                     DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${comp}.ecpp)`